# Over-serving an intoxicated customer

Tags: california, business, alcohol

I work for a cafe in Southern California. Recently a guest purchased five [mimosa cocktails](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mimosa_(cocktail)) over an hour time period, three of which were ordered within 20 minutes. The guest was by themselves the entire time so I have no reason to believe they were sharing the drinks with a friend.

When I approached my management on cutting off the guest they simply returned with a "They're fine". However, according to our alcohol training, we know this to be incorrect. Furthermore, several of the drinks were poured by a minor.

How and to whom should I go about reporting this?

Answer (score 4):

The criteria for refusing service in California is the patron being “obviously drunk”. 5 150ml mimosas is not a lot, even in an hour - it has approximately the same alcohol content as 2 425ml beers. I certainly wouldn’t be “obviously drunk” after that.

Only 18 year olds and over can serve or act as bartenders for on-premises consumption. Whether someone under 18 can pour drinks for someone else to serve is not clear. However, it’s probably ok as the legislative intention appears to be to put a responsible adult at the point of service.

The government authority responsible is [Alcoholic Beverage Control](https://www.abc.ca.gov).